# How can i use conditional formatting in excel to highlight any dates occuring 2 weeks ago?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight dates in an excel document that occur 2 weeks ago or more? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in conditional formatting, put the formula:

```
=A1<NOW()-14
```

And pick the formula you need. I'm assuming that the first date is in A1. Just put the first date and select the range of cells containing the range when you're applying the conditional formatting.

E.g. If the dates are in range A2:A5, click on A2 first, then select up to A5 (all those cells should be highlighted and cell A2 should be lighter).

If the dates are in column B, click B1 first, then click the 'B' header to select the whole column. B1 should be a bit lighter and all the rest blueish.

Answer (score 0):

select the column to format
click conditional formating
select lesser than and enter the value NOW()-14 or the date